# Как в controlfx в методе bindAutoCompletion очищать поля?

Tags: javafx

Доброго
есть строка
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, listTitle);

Туда заносятся данные для выпадающего списка, строки тянутся из бд. Так вот, я вношу изменения в бд и снова вызываю её, в итоге выходит, что при вводе он мне показывает в выпадающем списке новый результат, но при выборе может внести как новый результат, так и старый или после выбора нового предложить старый
т.е. при запуске есть "тумбочка2222", мы меняем название в бд на "тумбочка", в выпадающем спике она есть, при нажатии получаем "тумбочка2222"в поле TextField
[вот на док](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.html), но чёт не вижу решения

```
    public void UpdateTextFieldsBindAutoCompletion(TextFieldId textField) {
    String[] listTitle;

    switch (textField.getId()) {
        case "name_product_en":
            listTitle = InquirySQL.getInstance().getTitleProductEN().toArray(new String[0]);
            TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, listTitle);
            break;
        default:
            listTitle = InquirySQL.getInstance().getTitleProductRU().toArray(new String[0]);
            TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, listTitle);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите код того, как вы добавляете все строки в биндинг

Comment: Добавил в вопрос код. В listTitle приходит данные из бд, которые записываю до этого в Arraqy<String>